# search for specific Quarkus extension with command line

Tags: java, command-line, quarkus

I would like to search for specific **Quarkus** extension using command line for example spring-web. I know there is a command for listing all extensions ( **./mvnw quarkus:list-extensions** ) or add some one ( **./mvnw quarkus:add-extension -Dextensions="hibernate-validator"** ) but for finding extensions i don't know.

Can you help me please and thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quarkus plans to add cli tool to handle such cases, for now, you can filter output with grep
e.g

```
./mvnw quarkus:list-extensions | grep "mysql"
```